# Passing a variable into a WTForms class

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I'm relatively inexperienced with Python and Flask, and am stuck trying to pass a variable to a WTForms class.

Here's what I have:

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/teacher/tasks/new')
@login_required
def new_hw_task():
    classes = Class.query.filter_by(userid=current_user.userid).all()

    form = NewTaskForm(classes = classes)


    return render_template('/teacher/new_hw_task.html', form=form)
```

**forms.py**

```
class NewTaskForm(FlaskForm):

    classes = SelectMultipleField('Select classes to assign this homework to', choices = [("1", "Class 1"), ("2","Class 2")])
```

**new_hw_task.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
        {{ form.classes.label }}
        {{ form.classes(class_="form-control selectpicker", placeholder=form.classes.description, title="Select at least one class to assign", show_tick=true)}}
</div>
```

I want the `classes` variable (an instance of a `Class` class defined in **models.py** - yes, yes, I know how sloppy it is to have a class called 'Class') to be accessible in forms.py so that I can replace the choices in the `SelectMultipleField` with ones from `classes`. However, I can't find a way to pass it through (you can see that I've tried putting `classes=classes` into the parentheses after NewTaskForm).

Actually, my preferred way to do this would be to simply access `current_user` (the session-based object set by flask_login) from within **forms.py**, but I appear to be unable to do that either, even if I import current_user at the top of the file.

Is anybody able to explain to me where I'm going wrong here, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WTForms documentation for [`SelectField`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField) explains how to pass variables into a form from a view. It's as simple as assigning a list of choices to `form.field.choices`. In turn, you remove the `choices=` keyword argument from the field constructor.

Adapted for your case, it would look like this.

```
@app.route('/teacher/tasks/new')
@login_required
def new_hw_task():
    classes = Class.query.filter_by(userid=current_user.userid).all()

    form = NewTaskForm()
    form.classes.choices = classes


    return render_template('/teacher/new_hw_task.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had search for a long time, this solution is very useful and simple!