# can i change flask wtforms validators with variable

Tags: python, validation, variables, wtforms

this is form

```
class VideoUploadForm(FlaskForm):
  username = StringField('username', validators=[DataRequired()])
  title = StringField('title', validators=[DataRequired()]) #equalTo("필드네임")
  video = StringField('video', validators=[DataRequired()])
  start_h = IntegerField('start_h', validators=[NumberRange(min=0)],default=0)
  start_m = IntegerField('start_m', validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=59)],default=0)
  start_s = IntegerField('start_s', validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=59)],default=0)
  time = IntegerField('time', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1, max=60)], default=20)
  video_link = HiddenField('video_link', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

i tried

```
form=VideoUploadForm()
max_time = 120
form.time.validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1, max=max_time)]
return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

I referenced this webpage. but it didnt work
[Passing a variable into a WTForms class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59603650/passing-a-variable-into-a-wtforms-class)

Answer (score 0):

I use init to pass along any runtime context:

```
class VideoUploadForm(FlaskForm):
  username = StringField('username', validators=[DataRequired()])
  title = StringField('title', validators=[DataRequired()]) #equalTo("필드네임")
  video = StringField('video', validators=[DataRequired()])
  start_h = IntegerField('start_h', validators=[NumberRange(min=0)],default=0)
  start_m = IntegerField('start_m', validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=59)],default=0)
  start_s = IntegerField('start_s', validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=59)],default=0)
  time = IntegerField('time', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange()], default=20)
  video_link = HiddenField('video_link', validators=[DataRequired()])

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VideoUploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.time.validators[1] = NumberRange(min=1, max=kwargs['max_time'])
```

creating the form:

```
form = VideoUploadForm(max_time=120)
```